# What role does the indentation play here? and Why one indent doesn't work?

Tags: indentation, haskell

Here is a sample program from RWH book.  I'm wondering why the first works great but the second can't even compile? The only difference is the first one uses 2 tabs after `where mainWith func = do` whereas the second uses only 1. Not sure what difference does that mean? Why the second fails to compile? And also why `do construct` can be empty?

Thanks a lot, 
Alex

```
-- Real World Haskell Sample Code Chapter 4:
-- http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/functional-programming.html

import System.Environment (getArgs)

interactWith func input output = do
    s <- readFile input
    writeFile output (func s)

main = mainWith myFunction
    where mainWith func = do
            args <- getArgs
            case args of 
                [fin, fout] -> do
                    interactWith func fin fout
                _ -> putStrLn "error: exactly two arguments needed"

myFunction = id


-- The following code has a compilation error
-- % ghc --make interactWith.hs
-- [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( interactWith.hs, interactWith.o )
-- 
-- interactWith.hs:8:26: Empty 'do' construct


import System.Environment (getArgs)

interactWith func input output = do
    s <- readFile input
    writeFile output (func s)

main = mainWith myFunction
    where mainWith func = do
        args <- getArgs
        case args of 
            [fin, fout] -> do
                interactWith func fin fout
            _ -> putStrLn "error: exactly two arguments needed"

myFunction = id
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The definition of the `mainWith` function is indented to column 10:

```
    where mainWith func = do
          ^
```

The contents of the `do` block started in this line are only indented to column 8:

```
        args <- getArgs
        case args of 
            ...
        ^
```

If you increase the indentation of the contents of the `do` block to be also indented at least to column 10, the code is parsed correctly. With the current indentation the lines that should belong to the `do` block are seen to be part of the `where` clause, but not the `mainWith` function.

Comment: ah, wow, that's mysterious. 

Thanks a heap, that explains. Haven't expected the indent starts after 'where'.

Comment: @Alex: That's because the `where` has it's own indent level (starting as expected at the `w`). You could define several function in a single `where` block. The function definition self starts it's own indent level, separate of the one introduced by `where`.

Answer (score 0):

The `do`-block can not be empty, that's why you get the error. When using only one tab `args <- getArgs` is seen as part of the `where`-block, not the `do`-block, so the `do`-block is empty and you get an error.

The thing is that unless you use `{}` and `;` to explicitly state which block goes from where to where, haskell relies on indendation. And since you indented your line only by one level, it was seen as part of the `where`-block.